# Second activity can't read getExtras from intent

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-intent, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to get the values from a recyclerView item (Firestore as database) in a new activity by using intents if I click on it. Don't know if that is the best way, but I got so far.

In my second activity I only get Null in the textViews I want to populate.

I've tried to test it with Toasts. You will see there is two Toast messages. The first one in the mainActivity (UltraLiquors) show the data I want to pull correctly (the ID, product and price), but the second one in the details activity only shows "null", so I assume there is a problem with my getExtras in my detail activity. I just don't know where to look anymore.

Please be so kind and help, I really have been struggling with this a few days.

Here is my mainActivity (UltraLiquors.class)

```
public class UltraLiquors extends AppCompatActivity {

private FirebaseFirestore ultra_liquor_db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
private CollectionReference promo_oneRef = ultra_liquor_db.collection("ultra_liquors");
private static final int ACTIVITY_NUM = 2;

private UltraLiquorsRecyclerAdapter ultra_liquors_adapter;

private static final String TAG = "Ultra Liquors";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_ultra_liquors);
    setUpPromoOneRecyclerView();
    //setupBottomNavigationView();
    setTitle("Ultra Liquors");
    Context context;
}

private void setUpPromoOneRecyclerView() {
    Query query = promo_oneRef.whereEqualTo("promo_number", "1").orderBy("department");

    FirestoreRecyclerOptions<Ultra_liquors> options = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<Ultra_liquors>()
            .setQuery(query, Ultra_liquors.class)
            .build();

    ultra_liquors_adapter = new UltraLiquorsRecyclerAdapter(options);

    RecyclerView promo_one_recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view_ultra_liquors);
    //recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    promo_one_recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    promo_one_recyclerView.setAdapter(ultra_liquors_adapter);


    ultra_liquors_adapter.setOnItemClickListener(new UltraLiquorsRecyclerAdapter.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot, int position) {
            Ultra_liquors note = documentSnapshot.toObject(Ultra_liquors.class);
            String id = documentSnapshot.getId();
            String product = (String) documentSnapshot.get("product");
            String price = (String) documentSnapshot.get("price");
            String path = documentSnapshot.getReference().getPath();
            Toast.makeText(UltraLiquors.this,
                   "Position: " + position + " ID: " + product + price, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent intent = new Intent(UltraLiquors.this, ViewProduct.class);
            intent.putExtra("Product", product);
            intent.putExtra("Price", price);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    ultra_liquors_adapter.startListening();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    ultra_liquors_adapter.stopListening();
}
```

}

And here is the detailActivity (ViewProduct) where I want to pull the data from the intent:

```
public class ViewProduct extends AppCompatActivity {

private String edit_product_ID;
//private String edit_product_Product;
private String edit_product_Price;

private TextView productView, priceView;
private TextView mSave, mDelete;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.view_product);
Intent intent = getIntent();
String product;
String price;

product = String.valueOf(getIntent().getExtras().get("product"));
price = String.valueOf(getIntent().getExtras().get("price"));

    Toast.makeText(this, "The Product ID: " + edit_product_ID +
            " Product Name " + product + " Product Price " + price, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    TextView productView = findViewById(R.id.product);
    productView.setText(product);
    TextView priceView = findViewById(R.id.price);
    priceView.setText(price);
    mSave = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.save);
    mDelete = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.delete);

  }}
```

I am not the best yet with Java or Android, so please be patient.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using:

```
 intent.putExtra("Product", product);
 intent.putExtra("Price", price);
```

But then you're trying to get them with:

```
product = String.valueOf(getIntent().getExtras().get("product"));
price = String.valueOf(getIntent().getExtras().get("price"));
```

See how these values are different ?

You need to use the same casing, as it's case sensitive, so use something like:

```
product = String.valueOf(getIntent().getExtras().get("Product"));
price = String.valueOf(getIntent().getExtras().get("Price"));
```